# Spring boot embedded tomcat stops working after some time

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot application. I create a war file using that and run it using its own embedded tomcat. For e.g

```
java -jar first.war
```

This works fine. the context root is set to /first and when i hit the url

http://blahblah:8443/first it works fine.

Now, i have to run another war in the same port. So, i followed the link https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-add-war-to-embedded-tomcat/
and add another war file. This works fine, but only for sometime. For eg. when i bring up my application /second then both then /second becomes unreacheable after 24 hours.

```
http://blahblah:8443/first it works fine.
http://blahblah:8443/second it works fine only for some time.
```

I am suspecting that it the second url stops working at 12 midnight. There are basically no logs at all which has any error or exception. what could be the issue?

Comment: what is error in console?

Comment: there is no error in the logs. In the webpage it shows 404